# Ubuntu 12.10 not mounting internal hard drives

Tags: 12.10, mount

I just started using Ubuntu 12.10 and I do like the interface very much. I am not savy with the hip lingo of linux, so spare me the who I know what I am talking about.

I need help, I need to figure out why both of my hard drives won't "mount". I had an extra drive that I wasn't using, and I formatted it in windows, and then tried to do a clean install of Ubuntu on it and it went fine, but it said my hdd wasn't mounted. Then I had installed Ubuntu on my other HDD alongside Windows Vista, and I had no problems accessing my hdd space and viewing folders and what not.

So I thought that the other hdd had something wrong with it and went ahead and did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.10 on it instead and now I am in the same boat again. So I need to figure out how to mount my hdd in Ubuntu so I can put files on it. I want to use this system as my primary system for work, it will suit me perfect. Please

Comment: Can you see the HDDs in file manager? If so any error message when you clicked them? And you don't need to install ubuntu on same disk to view the files. I am not very sure what you are trying to do. Clarify a bit, like installed ubuntu in disk1, not seeing disk2 when booting with ubuntu like that.

Comment: Please keep polite, there is no need for that attitude.